# Correlate messages between 2 JMS queues using Spring integration components

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have 2 JMS queues and my application subscribes to both of them with `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(...)` component.

First queue receives messages of type `Paid`. Second queue receives messages of type `Reversal`.

Business scenario defines correlation between messages of type `Paid` and type `Reversal`.

`Reversal` should wait for `Paid` in order to be processed.

How can I achieve such "wait" pattern with Spring Integration?

Is it possible to correlate messages between 2 JMS queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation about the Aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#aggregator).

The aggregator correlates messages using some correlation strategy and releases the group based on some release strategy.

> The Aggregator combines a group of related messages, by correlating and storing them, until the group is deemed to be complete. At that point, the aggregator creates a single message by processing the whole group and sends the aggregated message as output.

The output payload is a list of the grouped message payloads by default, but you can provide a custom output processor.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So55299268Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55299268Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow in1(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .destination("queue1"))
                .channel("aggregator.input")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow in2(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .destination("queue2"))
                .channel("aggregator.input")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow aggregator() {
        return f -> f
                .aggregate(a -> a
                        .correlationExpression("headers.jms_correlationId")
                        .releaseExpression("size() == 2")
                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                        .expireGroupsUponTimeout(true)
                        .groupTimeout(5_000L)
                        .discardChannel("discards.input"))
                .handle(System.out::println);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow discards() {
        return f -> f.handle((p, h) -> {
            System.out.println("Aggregation timed out for " + p);
            return null;
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            send(template, "one", "two");
            send(template, "three", null);
        };
    }

    private void send(JmsTemplate template, String one, String two) {
        template.convertAndSend("queue1", one, m -> {
            m.setJMSCorrelationID(one);
            return m;
        });
        if (two != null) {
            template.convertAndSend("queue2", two, m -> {
                m.setJMSCorrelationID(one);
                return m;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

and

> GenericMessage [payload=[two, one], headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_destination=queue://queue1, jms_correlationId=one, id=784535fe-8861-1b22-2cfa-cc2e67763674, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1553290921442, jms_messageId=ID:Gollum2.local-55540-1553290921241-4:1:3:1:1, timestamp=1553290921457}]
>
> 2019-03-22 17:42:06.460  INFO 55396 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.a.AggregatingMessageHandler        : Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[three]
>
> Aggregation timed out for three

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is there any code example which showcases aggregator in action?

Comment: I added a simple example to the answer; the aggregator has lots of properties so you should explore them to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. What if I want to correlate messages where `Paid` transaction comes after 1 week since the time `Reversal` was received? It seems like I'd need to persist it into database and retrieve the record when I want to correlate.

Comment: Yes; see `.messageStore(...)`. The framework provides a [number of store implementations, including JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#message-store).